# Sql Server Reporting Services Webservice Exception on processing Parameter, preview in vs2015 works, call on report server works

Tags: c#, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

the error may have been caused by upgrading a VS 2013 solution to VS 2015.
During Migration the Report-Project could not be migrated so I had to add a new one and set Compatibility to "Sql Server 2008". According to another thread i deployed the .rdl File in the Debug-Folder to our ReportServer because the SourceFile still Points to 2016.

During preview the Parameter is selected via a Combobox, where the user the selects a string an an id is provided as Reportparameter.

ReportExecutionService.Render throws the Exception:

"
Error during processing of 'paraDepot' Report Parameter. ---> 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
 "Error during processing of 'paraDepot' Report Parameter.

```
<ReportParameters>
<ReportParameter Name="paraDepot">
<DataType>String</DataType>
<DefaultValue>
<DataSetReference>
<DataSetName>DepotNames</DataSetName>
<ValueField>ID_DEPOT</ValueField>
</DataSetReference>
</DefaultValue>
<Prompt>Depot</Prompt>
<ValidValues><DataSetReference>
<DataSetName>DepotNames</DataSetName>
<ValueField>ID_DEPOT</ValueField>
<LabelField>DEPOT</LabelField>
</DataSetReference></ValidValues>
</ReportParameter>
...
</ReportParameters>
```

The Report has got only some additional fields but it it the same as the one deployed from a Windows7 Environment from vs 2013.
So I copied the Report into another File lets say ReportV2015.rdl.

If I take a report-Path to the Report-File deployed form Windows7, lets call it ReportV2013.rdl than the Render method works.

So could this behaviour be caused by an unlucky combnination of Version of installed libraries?  Is the Version of SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) important?

Also VS2015 and VS2013 runs on different Virtual Machines. So, for which Libraries I would had to check the Versions?

The ReportService calls: ReportServer/Reportexecution2005.asmx.
The Render Method uses the DevInfo Parameter: @"False"

Any ideas are appreciated.
Actually I fear to have to downgrade to vs2013 again and Remake the Upgrades in the Reportfile as I spent already about 2 days with any result.

So this is how the Report is called from Application:

```
ReportExecutionService loReportingService = new ReportExecutionService();
loReportingService.Url = "http://10.20.30.40/ReportServer/Reportexecution2005.asmx"; // (IP changed)
loReportingService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential( ltReportuser, ltReportPassword, ltReportDomain );

string ltDevInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

// Setting the Parameters:
ParameterValue loDepot = new ParameterValue();
                loDepot.Name = "paraDepot";
                loDepot.Value = poShift.ID_DEPOT.ToString();
// ... ParameterValue loShiftType ...           

ParameterValue loShiftDate = new ParameterValue();
loShiftDate.Name = "paraDate";
// loShiftDate.Value = poShift.DATE.ToString( "dd/MM/yyyy" ); // seems to make no difference
loShiftDate.Value = poShift.DATE.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

ParameterValue[] laReportingServiceParameter = { loDepot, loShiftType, loShiftDate };

string ltHistoryID = null; // ltReportPath is just the Path to the .rdl File
loReportingService.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
//Load the Report
var execInfo = loReportingService.LoadReport( ltReportPath, ltHistoryID );
//Set Parameters for Report
execInfo = loReportingService.SetExecutionParameters( laReportingServiceParameter, "de-DE" );

// Instruction which throws the Exception:
result = loReportingService.Render( "PDF", ltDevInfo, out ltExtension, out ltEncoding, out ltMimeType, out laWarnings, out laStreamIDs );
```

Some Details to the SoapException:

```
<ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
rsReportParameterProcessingError
</ErrorCode>
<HttpStatus xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
400
</HttpStatus>
<Message xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
Error during processing of ‘paraDepot’ report parameter.
</Message>
<HelpLink xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsReportParameterProcessingError&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.5058.0
</HelpLink>
<ProductName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services
</ProductName>
<ProductVersion xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">11.0.5058.0</ProductVersion>
<ProductLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">127</ProductLocaleId>
<OperatingSystem xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">OsIndependent</OperatingSystem>
<CountryLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">1033</CountryLocaleId>
<MoreInformation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices"><Source>Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore</Source>
<Message msrs:ErrorCode="rsReportParameterProcessingError" msrs:HelpLink="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsReportParameterProcessingError&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.5058.0" xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Error during processing of ‘paraDepot’ report parameter.</Message>
</MoreInformation>
<Warnings xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices"/>
```

Best Regards

Comment: Can you show the code that invokes the Report Execution service?

Comment: Can you add the whole method and put it in the question? Thanks

Comment: Well I added the 4 Spaces but somehow the Code is not beeing formatted correctly in the comments....

Comment: The Call to "loReportingService.Render(...)" throws the exception mentioned at the top. Is something wrong with the use of Parameter?

Comment: Hi.. edit it your question and add the code in there. CTRL K will format it when highlighted.

Comment: Ok I moved the snippet in the question.

Comment: Hmmm... Seems ok to me.... Can you execute your report on the SSRS server itself. So browse to the report where you've uploaded the .rdl and get results?

Comment: Yes, I can start the Report on ReportServer in Internet Explorer.
I just have to Setup the 3 Parameters.
But I have to supply the SQL-user/pwd combination to the datasource used in the Report like in the preview in vs2015.

Comment: Well the only difference between what I'm doing and yourself is that my language is set to en-US. Dont know if this is affecting anything. Are you sure that your paraDepot value from poShift.ID_DEPOT.ToString() is valid? I'll post my code for you to have a look at

Comment: See below. Perhaps include the SOAP exception catch and see if you can get anymore info

Comment: Yes the Value is "6".

Comment: I added the InnerXml of soapException.Detail into the Question.

Comment: Wow.. that doesn't give you a lot does it. One last thing. What date format is your SQL Server. Have you tried using en-US as the language and formatting the date as .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") . I have encountered odd problems before if the date are incorrect.

Comment: I have tried the amarican date but I still get the Error on the paraDepot Parameter.

Comment: On https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e769c06a-ba51-4ced-a6f3-7c8bb7f9bab3/soapexception-while-rendering-report-through-webservice-error-during-processing-of?forum=sqlreportingservices someone is writing sth. on credential-Problems causing this Kind of Error-Message. Is this possible?

Comment: I will start my Weekend, so I wish you a good Weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally dared it.  I renamed the new Report to old File Name and I have overwritten the original one.   The Dataset-Connections stored on Server have remained and now it works.

Now the original Problem is solved but I would like to know why I cannot store the DataSource Connection on the new uploaded File.

I get sth. like in

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4433567b-76d4-4864-b444-f57edf7efb14/rsaccessdenied-sql-server-2012-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices

If I would have to upload once a 2nd Report I will be lost then. For now I can live with this and hope that noone destroys accidently the Settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected ParameterValue[] ReportPrameters;

   private void GetPDFByteStreamFromService()
            {
                var execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();
                var deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

                var reportService = new ReportExecutionService()
                {
                    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
                    Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceURL"),
                    Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite
                };

                reportService.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;
                reportService.LoadReport(ReportPathInSSRS(), null);

                SetReportParameter();

                reportService.SetExecutionParameters(ReportPrameters, "en-us");

                try
                {
                    const string reportFormat = "PDF";

                    CurrentStatement.StatementsPDFBytes = reportService.Render(reportFormat, deviceInfo, out string extension, out string mimeType,
                        out string encoding, out Warning[] warnings, out string[] streamIDs);
                }
                catch (SoapException ex)
                {
                    Log.Error($"GetPDFByteStreamFromService SoapExcetpion: {ex.Message}", ex);
                    throw new Exception($"Error generating PDF Report");
                }
            }

public virtual void SetReportParameter()
        {

            ReportPrameters = new ParameterValue[3];
            ReportPrameters[0] = new ParameterValue()
            {
                Name = "Param1",
                Value = "1"
            };

            ReportPrameters[1] = new ParameterValue()
            {
                Name = "Param2",
                Value = "false"
            };

            ReportPrameters[2] = new ParameterValue()
            {
                Name = "Code",
                Value = "XYZ"
            };

            return;
        }
```